# Enable and disable buttons from a switch from different file

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm new to react and front development any help would be appreciate, please don't make stack overflow a toxic place, laughing or closing the tick you think it is too simple or stupid. No question is stupid

A `Button` is stored in file **panel.tsx** a `Switch` is located in **notes.tsx** file the enable and disable status of the `button` is decided by the `switch` condition in the **notes.tsx** file.

The following code is a simplified version of the issue described above

```
# notes.tsx
export const AddNotes: React.FC = () => {
    const [skipNotes, setSkipNotes] = useState(false);
    const onSkipNotes = (checked: boolean) => setSkipNotes(checked);
 
    return (
        <div>
            <CC.ToggleSwitch checked={skipNotesAndTags} onChange={onSkipNotes} label="Skip notes" changeHighlight />
        </div>
    );
};


# panel.tsx
export const Panel: React.FC = () => {
  <div>
      <CC.Button text={'Submit'} disabled={true}/> // How can I disabled/enable it based on skipNotes from note.tsx
  </div>
```

How can I disabled/enable the **Button** based on **skipNotes** from notes.tsx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [lift the state](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html). If you read over that section of the docs I linked, it should make sense; they explain it really well.

But just to try and explain, the `useState` hook for `skipNotes` should be placed in the common parent of notes and panel. Then you pass `skipNotes` and `setSkipNotes` in as props.

```js
export const App: React.FC<Props> = ({}) => {
  const [skipNotes, setSkipNotes] = useState(false)
  return <>
    <AddNotes skipNotes={skipNotes} setSkipNotes={setSkipNotes} />
    <Panel skipNotes={skipNotes} />
  </>
}



export const AddNotes: React.FC = (skipNotes, setSkipNotes) => {
  const onSkipNotes = (checked: boolean) => setSkipNotes(checked)
  return (
    <div>
      <CC.ToggleSwitch checked={skipNotes} onChange={onSkipNotes} label="Skip notes" changeHighlight />
    </div>
  )
}


export const Panel: React.FC = (skipNotes) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <CC.Button text="Submit" disabled={skipNotes}/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank @geekTechnique for kind and detailed explanation, much appreciate

Answer (score 1):

there are couple solutions for your question

1. to globalize your state and the simplest way is by using useContext hook
2. or just simply pass the state as props from a parent component to its child
   here is a react js example (instead of ts I hope that's fine) of how it's done
   [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-euler-s16u6k?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Don't post a link-only answer, include the important snippets from the link directly in your  answer as well in case the link breaks in the future.

Comment: @Muhamand Thanks so much to provide me resource and help me to understood more about react state